# Push notification open Activity with same intent

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I receive push notifications with data(intent). If I received two or more notifications with different ids, but open one Activity and ids are same. For example, I receive three notifications with different id=1,2,3. But when Activity is started use one id = 3. When I click first or second notification with ids 1 and 2, open Activity with id 3.Can you help understand my mistake in the code?

```
NOTIFICATION_ID ++;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(msg.getString("title"))
        .setContentText(msg.getString("message"))
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(msg.getString("icon")).get()).setSummaryText(msg.getString("message")))        
        .setAutoCancel(true);

        Log.e("msg---",msg.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, ActivityDetail.class));
//        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
//        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Keys._PostId,msg.getString("id"));
        intent.putExtra(Keys._Image, msg.getString("icon"));
        intent.putExtra(Keys._PostType,  msg.getString("post_type"));       
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: You need to set `PendingIntent`  as per your ids.

Comment: please try this  may be it will help for you `PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` thanks;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create your `PendingIntent` like this and do a trick

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) (Math.random() * 100), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: saved my day :) Thanks bro @BirajZalavadia